# PHP array foreach while loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, while-loop

I am trying to create javascript variable from php, this is what i want to get.

```
<?PHP echo "var color_name=[<?PHP echo $color_name;?>]"; //var color_name=["Green","Pink"];

<?PHP echo "var style_name=[<?PHP echo $style_name;?>]"; //var style_name=["Basic","Classic"];
```

this is my predefined_attributes table
[image: this is my predefined_attributes table]

this is what i have tried,

```
<?php
$predifined_qry = "SELECT attribute_column_name 
                    FROM predefined_attributes 
                    WHERE category_id=$id";
$predifined_result = mysqli_query($predifined_qry);
$columnNames = Array();
while ($predifined_result_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($predifined_result)) {
    $columnNames[] = $predifined_result_row['attribute_column_name'];
}
```

now i can get the `attribute_column_name` in an array using a foreach loop, but i dont know how to get the `attribute_column_value` array in a variable like this `$style_name`, `$color_name`. please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you only need 1 column, and the resource/data you get is not massive, you could just fetch all and extract the column

You could expose your php variables in js through JSON

```
<?php

$predifined_result = mysqli_query($predifined_qry);
$predifined_rows = mysqli_fetch_all($predifined_result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$columnNames = array_column($predifined_rows, 'attribute_column_name');
?>


<script>
    var columnames = JSON.parse("<?= json_encode($columnNames); ?>");
</script>
```

So now if we add in the other field :

```
<?php

$predifined_result = mysqli_query($predifined_qry);
$predifined_rows = mysqli_fetch_all($predifined_result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$columnNames = array_column($predifined_rows, 'attribute_column_name');
$columnValues = array_column($predifined_rows, 'attribute_column_value');
// array_combines uses the first array as the key and the second as the value
$columns = array_combine($columnNames, $columnValues);
?>

<script>
    var columns = JSON.parse("<?= json_encode($columns); ?>");
</script>
```

Edit
as in the comments, a key can only appear once in a hashtable/array
so we need to generate an array of values per key

```
<?php
$predifined_qry = "SELECT attribute_column_name, attribute_column_value 
                FROM predefined_attributes 
                WHERE category_id=$id";
$predifined_result = mysqli_query($predifined_qry);
$columns = [];
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($predifined_result)) {
    if(!array_key_exists($row['attribute_column_name'], $columns)) {
        $columns[$row['attribute_column_name']] = [];
    }
    $columns[$row['attribute_column_name']][] = $row['attribute_column_value'];
}
?>

<script>
    var columns = JSON.parse("<?= json_encode($columns); ?>");
</script>
```

Comment: thank you, i have tried your solution, i am getting this output closest to what i want `{"color_name":"Green","style_name":"Basic"} `  can you please help to get the output like this `{"color_name":"Green","color_name":"Pink","style_name":"Basic","style_name":"Classic"} `

Comment: you can use `ksort($columns);` to sort the array by the keys  of the columns

Comment: thank you, actually i am getting one key once like this `{"color_name":"Green","style_name":"Basic"}` it is not repeating like this `{"color_name":"Green","color_name":"Pink","style_name":"Basi‌​c","style_name":"Cla‌​ssic"}`

Comment: you're right, slight mistake on my end, let me edit my answer, what you want is not possible, as you can only have each key once

Comment: thank you so much, it is giving the expected output now, works great.

Comment: one quick question, how do i get the variable like this `var color_name=["Green","Pink"];` `var style_name=["Basic","Classic"];` could you please advice

Comment: `var style_name = columns.style_name, color_name = columns.color_name`

Answer (score 1):

**1st :** You need to select `attribute_column_value` column  too

```
SELECT attribute_column_name,attribute_column_value FROM predefined_attributes where category_id=$id
```

**2nd :**  You need push both column value in two different array like this

```
while ( $predifined_result_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($predifined_result) ) {
    $color_name[] = $predifined_result_row['attribute_column_name'];
    $style_name[] = $predifined_result_row['attribute_column_value'];
    }
```

**3rd :** simple apply `json_enocde` and echo like this

```
<script>
  var color_name=<?php echo json_encode($color_name); ?>; 
  var style_name=<?php echo json_encode($style_name); ?>;
 </script>
```

Comment: thank you, `$color_name[] = $predifined_result_row['attribute_column_name'];` i believe this will not have array of color_name field. instead this will hold the array of attribute_column_name fields.

Answer (score -1):

```
$columnValues[] = $predifined_result_row['attribute_column_value'];
```

You can paste this code into your `while` loop

And dont't forget to get the need field form database:

```
$predifined_qry="SELECT attribute_column_name,attribute_column_value FROM predefined_attributes where category_id=$id";
```

Comment: Not a very constructive answer, better show the whole code, of what is needed